# Align Buttons Over Image Without Using Vertical Space

Tags: css, positioning

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFNAF/17/

Notice the green background and the image overlaying it. The previous/next "buttons" are positioned over the photo. This causes there to be blank space above the photo where the buttons were originally positioned. I want to float the buttons over the photo as shown but without "using" the space above the photo. E.g. I want the buttons to be positioned absolutely but still relative to their container. Also notice that the `div.Image` is centered using an auto left/right margin. This makes it so that `position: absolute` cannot be used.

**Edit:** The image should be top-aligned with the green box. The buttons should be offset 10px below the top of the image and 10px from the left/right of the image. Different size images will be displayed so the image size cannot be set in CSS.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Where should the red buttons be in relation to the green box?

Comment: Adding to description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.Image,
.Image img
{
    width:366px;
    height:341px;
    border:0;
}
.Image
{
    position:relative;
}
.Image a
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:28px;
    height:28px;
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
.Image a.Previous
{
    left:10px;
}
.Image a.Next
{
    right:10px;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Image">
    <a href="" class="Previous">&lt;</a>
    <a href="" class="Next">&gt;</a>
    <img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31500000/Happy-Hyena-hyenas-31563531-385-358.jpg">
</div>
```

**​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eFNAF/19/)**

---

### Updated:

Change this:

```
.Image,
.Image img
{
    width:366px;
    height:341px;
    border:0;
}
.Image
{
    position:relative;
}
```

to:

```
img
{
    border:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.Image
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/eFNAF/27/)**

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, but I can't set the width/height of the image, the buttons need to adapt to different size images.

Comment: ...I know I did in the CSS but it was just for clarity. I will update my fiddle!

Comment: Updated my answer. :) Is this what you were looking for?